# Spring cloud kafka combinaison function

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

With spring cloud, i saw we can define combinaison functions seperated with a pipe. I m wondering if this feature is also available with spring cloud **kafka streams** binder.

For example :
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition: upperCase|firstLetterLowerCase

I didn't find any examples available on that topic (only on Kafka binder). I guess i m missing something :/

Can you help me ?

Comment: Function composition is not supported in the Kafka Streams binder. What is your use case? We haven't found that much evidence for this as a requirement in Kafka Streams binder.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, i was hopping to share code between functions and split our business logic into smaller kstream.